Compare coordinate against list of locations
To put it simply I have a list of locations, where each location has it's own long, lat and radius.
I need to check whether an input long, lat is inside any of the locations, so just comparing the input long, lat if its inside any of the locations sphere.
I am using mongodb, I saw something similar in their documentation, using geoWithin and centerSphere, but these work if there its a fixed radius for all locations, where in my case each location has its own radius
This is the provided example in the docs
db.<collection>.find( {
   <location field> : {
      $geoWithin : {
         $centerSphere: [
            [ <input longitude>, <input latitude> ],
            <fixed radius>
         ]
       }
    }
 } )


In an aggregation pipeline, you can use $geoNear to compute distance to the point you specified and store it in a field, say named calculated_distance. Then you can compare calculated_distance with your radius to see if the point fall inside your circle.
db.location.aggregate([
  {
    "$geoNear": {
      "near": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          // your input here
          53.23,
          67.12
        ]
      },
      "distanceField": "calculated_dist"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $lte: [
          "$calculated_dist",
          "$radius"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
